# Wordpress / Jquery ajax, get works post fails with jquery error

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery

Hi all the following function will work and do exactly as I want it to but I want this to be a .post not a .get can anyone see a problem with the following? its pretty much straight from another answer on stack overflow and should work fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //This function adds a development.
        jQuery('#add_dev').bind('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            action: 'AjaxAddDev',
            security: AjaxHandler.ajaxnonce,
            name: jQuery('#dev_name').val(),
            desc: jQuery('#dev_desc').val()
        };        
        //alert(data['name']+data['desc']);
        jQuery.get(
                AjaxHandler.ajaxurl,
                data,
                function(response) {
                    // ERROR HANDLING
                    if (!response.success) {
                        // No data came back, maybe a security error
                        if (!response.data) {
                            //$('#my-answer').html('AJAX ERROR: no response');
                            alert("Problem adding Development");
                        } else {
                            //$('#my-answer').html(response.data.error);
                            alert(response.data);
                        }
                    } else {
                        //$('#my-answer').html(response.data);
                        alert("Problem adding Development");
                    }
                }
        );
    });
});
```

The error I get when I set it to .post is:

```
l.send(n.hasContent && n.data || null), r = function (e, i) {
```

Which is line 2963 of an un-minified version of jquery

```
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
```

Can anyone point me in the right Direction?

Updated Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //This function adds a development.
        jQuery('#add_dev').bind('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            action: 'AjaxAddDev',
            security: AjaxHandler.ajaxnonce,
            name: jQuery('#dev_name').val(),
            desc: jQuery('#dev_desc').val()
        };        
        //alert(data['name']+data['desc']);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: AjaxHandler.ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown['error']);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am using firefox latest version,

I got the following returned as an errotThrowen['error']

```
function () {
                if (l) {
                    var t = l.length;
                    (function i(t) {
                        x.each(t, function (t, n) {
                            var r = x.type(n);
                            "function" === r ? e.unique && p.has(n) || l.push(n) : n && n.length && "string" !== r && i(n)
                        })
                    })(arguments), n ? o = l.length : r && (s = t, c(r))
                }
                return this
            }
```

Comment: you do realise this will only work on JQuery 1.7 and below

Comment: i may be wrong, but i will post an example post ajax as an answer for you

Comment: Oh thanks man I literally spent the last 3 hours trying to work this out. I feel so stupid right now, at least that's something new to add to my troubleshooting list.

Comment: i've looked i don't think that it is an issue in anything above 1.7 actually however the bit i used below im using 1.9.1

Comment: I updated my post its still giving me an error on the same line.

Comment: are you able to change your jquery to 1.9.1? and also what is the error? and on what browser? can you update your post with it

Comment: can i just ask is the form been generated after the webpage is loaded? as if it is then the .bind needs to be outside the (document).ready( as it will attempt to bind the ajax to a button that doesn't yet exist if not have you tried $('#form_id').submit(function(e) {

Comment: OK its to do with the "Security" function in the ajax data, removing it will mean it works fine in terms of sending and receiving a response but it will not work because the security token is missing at least im on the right track now.

Comment: good to hear! glad your on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ajax on change

```
$("#yourid").change(function () {            
        var p = {
            postfieldname: value,
            postfieldname: value,
            postfieldname: value,
            postfieldname: value,
            postfieldname: value,
            postfieldname: value,
            postfieldname: value,
             }
        $.ajax({
            url: "library/test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: p,
            success: function (e) {
                var t = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
                $("#id").val(t['a']);
            }
        })
    })
```

and on test.php

```
$array = array("a" => "test", "b" => "array");
$encode = json_encode($aray);
echo $encode;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this was kind of an odd one,

To get it working I simply had to add the following as the post URL.

```
url: AjaxHandler.ajaxurl+"&security="+AjaxHandler.ajaxnonce,
```

If I left the security out of the url it would fail, I don't know why but this had me going around in circles for hours.